# How to fix these problems regarding phpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, ubuntu-18.04

How can I fix this problem regarding phpMyAdmin?

https://prnt.sc/nqtdkd

The errors occurred when click the Export/Import from the menu tab. I can't proceed when creating table also because of:

> Error in Processing Request. Error Code: 500

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the issue might be due to insufficient size of PHP memory limit. You may try editing the php.ini file and increase the memory_limit, max_input_vars parameters. You may use the "find / -name *php.ini" command to locate your php.ini file and use vi command to edit the file once you have logged in to the server via SSH.

; max_input_vars = 1000

memory_limit = 128M

You need to remove the semicolon for max_input_vars and increase the values of memory_limit and max_input_vars. After editing, don't forget to restart the Apache service.

$ service apache2 restart

Lastly, you can create a phpinfo.php file in the document root to check if you successfully increase the value of max_input_vars and memory_limit. Edit the file named phpinfo.php and copy the following code.

`<?php
phpinfo();
?>`

To access the phpinfo.php file, please use this link http:///phpinfo.php

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank you @Lherben G, this really helps! :)